# removing elements from xml via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, reporting-services

I am new to XSLT and so have been using various web pages and forums in an attempt to strip out elements from an xml file produced via SSRS.

The output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="xlst_x0020_test" xsi:schemaLocation="xlst_x0020_test http://reportserver?%2Fxlst%20test&amp;rs%3AFormat=XML&amp;rc%3ASchema=True" Name="xlst test">
  <resultset>
    <detail_collection>
      <Detail>
        <title>movie 1</title>
        <year>2000</year>
        <genre>comedy</genre>
      </Detail>
      <Detail>
        <title>movie 2</title>
        <year>2010</year>
        <genre>animation</genre>
      </Detail>
      <Detail>
        <title>movie 3</title>
        <year>1990</year>
        <genre>action</genre>
      </Detail>
    </detail_collection>
  </resultset>
</Report>
```

I would like to remove the elements "resultset" and "detail_collection" so the output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="xlst_x0020_test" xsi:schemaLocation="xlst_x0020_test http://reportserver?%2Fxlst%20test&amp;rs%3AFormat=XML&amp;rc%3ASchema=True" Name="xlst test">
    <Detail>
        <title>movie 1</title>
        <year>2000</year>
        <genre>comedy</genre>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <title>movie 2</title>
        <year>2010</year>
        <genre>animation</genre>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <title>movie 3</title>
        <year>1990</year>
        <genre>action</genre>
    </Detail>
</Report>
```

I have created the following xslt following advice on here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="resultset | detail_collection">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which results in the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report Name="xlst test" xmlns="xlst_x0020_test">
  <resultset>
    <detail_collection>
      <Detail>
        <title>movie 1</title>
        <year>2000</year>
        <genre>comedy</genre>
      </Detail>
      <Detail>
        <title>movie 2</title>
        <year>2010</year>
        <genre>animation</genre>
      </Detail>
      <Detail>
        <title>movie 3</title>
        <year>1990</year>
        <genre>action</genre>
      </Detail>
    </detail_collection>
  </resultset>
</Report>
```

I am hoping there is a simple mistake I have made, but just can't see it, can anyone help?

Also, does anybody have any good websites, books, videos etc which starts at the basics for xslt?

Comment: Powershell can go through an XML file and pull out what you need also.  Might be worth a look unless you absolutely need to accomplish this using XSLT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you have made is that you have not accounted for namespaces. Your `Report` element has a default namespace declaration

```
<Report ... xmlns="xlst_x0020_test">
```

This means the `Report` element, and all its descendants, are in a namespace. But you have not accounted for this namespace in the XSLT. It is trying to match `resultset` and `detail_collection` in no namespace, and these are not the same as elements in a namespace, even if the name itself is the same.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:test="xlst_x0020_test">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="test:resultset | test:detail_collection">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the namespace prefix used in the XSLT does not matter. It is the URI that must match with the XML.

Read up on namespaces here: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/1999/01/namespaces.html and http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/04/04/trxml/